# Robot Trigonometry 2D Inverse Kinematics, two servos angles

Tags: trigonometry

A small model is worth a thousand words:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I am building a machine that uses two servos which controls two angles ($a$ & $b$), connected to five equal distance (d) arms in 2D. To position an end point in 2D - $P_3$.

If I say that the point about angle $a$ is $(0,0)$.

Then
$P_1$ is at $(-\cos(a)\cdot d, \sin(a)\cdot d)$
$P_2$ is at $(d+\cos(b)\cdot d, \sin(b)\cdot d)$

Drawing a line between these two points. One side of the newer triangle is $x = d + \cos(b)\cdot d + \cos(a)\cdot d$ and $y = \sin(b)\cdot d - \sin(a)\cdot d$.

So that $L = sqrt(x^2 + y^2)$

That follows that
$$h = \sqrt{d^2 - \left(\frac L2\right)^2}$$

I also know that the mid point of $L$ is halfway between $P_1$ and $P_2$.

But now I am stuck, I not sure how I get $c$ or $d$, to enable me to get to $P_3$.

Any pointers would be great.

See Also:

> [image]
>
> - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCARA#/media/File:5R_robot.gif

Similar to [Calculating angles neccessary to reach a position on a 2D plane for two robot arms in a row](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1423467/calculating-angles-neccessary-to-reach-a-position-on-a-2d-plane-for-two-robot-ar)

Answer (score 0):

Once I worked out the maths, 
Make three triangles, I also worked out how to google ....

http://forums.reprap.org/file.php?185,file=51935